# Cakephp pagination styles

Tags: php, cakephp

Anyone have any idea to style the pagination in cakephp,I want to display the pagination links like below

`<< <<   <<   10  11  12  13   Page 14 of 75 (223 items)  15   16  17  18  >>    >>>>`

Please advise me,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1233/Pagination-in-Views

Most of it you can do with the helper, but you'll have to do "10 11 12 13" and "15 16 17 18" parts manually with some loops and calculations.

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< << <<', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); 

//insert previous numbers here

echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
    'format' => 'Page %page% of %pages% (%count% items)'
)); 

//insert next numbers here

echo $this->Paginator->next('>> >>>>', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
```

Comment: @RintoGeorge: "Thanks ,you've saved my time" is best expressed "[by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)".

Comment: I was hoping he would get to that. Thanks!